# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: even if attr_accessible already added

Tags: attr-accessible

Can't mass assign **:title**, **:url** and **:about** even if **attr_accessible** attributes already added. It's fine on rails console but not on online form.

Post Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :about, :downv, :names, :points, :title, :upv, :url, :user_id

    belongs_to :user

end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :password_digest, :post_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :name

    has_many :posts
    has_secure_password

    validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
end
```

Post Controller create:

```
def create
    @post = User.new(params[:post])
    @post.upv, @post.downv, @post.points = 0, 0, 0

    @post.user_id = params[:user_id]
    @post.names = ""

    if @post.save
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Post created."
    else
      render "new"
    end
end
```

My form view is is just like any other form view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of Post.new I typed User.new, SOLVED!!!